# How to force lazy-OR evaluation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, lazy-evaluation, boolean-logic

I am reading in data from a database and putting it in a `DataRow`.

I want to test a nullable boolean field for whether it is `Null` or `True`.

How can I do the following in VB.NET without it throwing an exception about how the `Or` operator cannot have `DBNull` as one of its operands?  Can I force lazy-OR evalution so that is just evaluates the `IsNull` and proceeds no further?

`If row.IsNull("MyNullableBooleanField") Or row("MyNullableBooleanField")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the 'OrElse' operator:

```
If row.IsNull("MyNullableBooleanField") OrElse row("MyNullableBooleanField") Then
```